# FindSequenceFunction with very small numbers

Tags: fitting, sequence

I need some help with `FindSequenceFunction` because at the moment it seems like a black box to me. For example, it deals with

```
testList = {12577/7350, 110939/66150, 2506963/1600830, 5098763/3513510, 86770513/64414350, 2124923459/1692340650, 27627071782/23497499025, 
 72754951853/65792997270, 2137915883317/2047323267990, 6665239656979/6734616013125, 24445165282768/25976376050625, 
 100280967236063/111744922038750, 62655882089725987/73023071653882350, 36695630047649021/44625210455150325, 
 15467017963009567/19584731861194500, 1807475878338537509/2378439331433290125, 4118187718509727777/5621765692478685750, 
 381930606606603478243/540010750231809756900, 29339686629753887741/42902929453814129700, 10308540397006034860181/15568813053720627450750, 
 24473768786974952044744/38128057689211603147125, 757882699833584088371833/1216551049990658593438500, 
 928282941762602315429/1533657237659710499700, 12126819954090587903743139/20600695847590042486691025, 
 291509462174587455511724069/508711060726203089977472250, 57714940202848561504763657/103374440147570681385796500, 
 40658939295508255533955866857/74685107314917527564972335500, 1342151988472229210325233257537/2526393493807346546084200549050, 
 1039190785244430640905635798/2003105918974336535066382675, 3119134162273347094985547930287/6152590756551343506520845226500, 
 448896234821414623503227414194897/905540324792097737730231941697000, 8293750969315385822770290630661/17099694146320400630373837979500, 
 9130513708337757637838541178576019/19229132211972561905797853849116350, 2845342435950698042425036246857157193/
  6117734063140404919163985860414389800, 3030950124059895119206031528984334893/6649710938196092303439115065667815000, 
 69496447776311306220186696350902/155504104308778917751536084733125, 12286033755067647892189099701697846001/
  28024881512345425859574051695333767500, 78131619786150088388948777416180310797/181601232199998359570039854985762813400, 
 6863039802782551009284687106678633221971/16247414137997255832181877415544415863800, 
 3626422966015873995169219309483813858969/8740697479302321175540883419754907268500};
```

producing a very non-trivial answer

```
Simplify[FindSequenceFunction[
  Transpose[{Table[n, {n, 1, Length[testList]}], testList}], p]]

(-4267 + 5040*EulerGamma - 9732*p + 11340*EulerGamma*p - 3664*p^2 + 3780*EulerGamma*p^2 + 1680*PolyGamma[0, 9/2] + 
  3780*p*PolyGamma[0, 9/2] + 1260*p^2*PolyGamma[0, 9/2] + 1260*(4 + 9*p + 3*p^2)*PolyGamma[0, 2 + p] - 
  420*(4 + 9*p + 3*p^2)*PolyGamma[0, 7/2 + p])/(70*(1 + 2*p)*(3 + 2*p)*(5 + 2*p))
```

However, my limited experience seems to indicate that `FindSequenceFunction` struggles when the numbers are very small. An example I would like to determine a formula for is

```
toDetermine={484556711/173918745000, 92904814076/1197225238584375, 220405081177/38995772653918080, 106429296661928/147806229137457515625, 
 266742039233278891/2023801175830980036090600, 107045013984614686004/3442693574901066509263865625, 
 7535634977764570621/851641733082791046052800000, 23428908644672945695696/8054310925812339533841981266925, 
 1616796478996744109547827/1507843018692955923925163592375000, 3043603644897313636783384/7016262273323095787890512129107595, 
 11006346360211501858585274303/58060973218760554015146610065037500000, 694924724646875809146779180312/
  7861144034430095642905392495960732421875, 9137603582368621808826657588601/209695884325568508931911247375064167709400, 
 3447103088014601404676679294632/152968380150282608676123960284670631734375, 
 47746835194520481461067944860183/3929275833409038076800003834789894232670208, 3822317891739549314175846703778328185632/
  562237777557725012384586989735152822554712478334375, 4258925756201376253278859620455883899/
  1083749045249382014674542985991211960522741093750, 6310045359740850547133881042540317718/
  2697878619086425775956338838277825875370399266365, 7360633171010632007513529806115115891960807/
  5150828090154183514384946641864198675469930789172000000, 358632865159582308514596888298242093538115152/
  401137524458814408047258799332798585147909740365788815665, 1288933811050975124137555099637301064567796819/
  2255336483376533056901064454500096731205484262022808425000, 2812185579198176453508961944318120554859146042/
  7548144250293895822634801861379602673979417521519785484375, 2165959097058218501040520692648339061170809659543/
  8759064188377487037864171550143838890507887014267724551065600, 131414369445702894524063013004070266800455347472/
  787567872388846560576799131107125125328432312965284677734375, 4641506408083477416346128987778894710633152573311940761/
  40599932937827569284397867045600795248953014301882040896940126418278, 344994790562878574218080733976928362096560390295402474662582/
  4342884149940353084465698175371316646062088785892357807425744851616559375, 13428163377941306184931072440078813809568457102767047722133/
  240104802495769872805953608000767575431434635030652762301740985028000000, 7172203265804021990065655001406272078936740985485839177712/
  179957322273684610400250945185582455620339169590368481968970063459694425, 14156299836636502740646699027663739984863212375910019309711/
  492797747873696497208081024047476941914955469037274180919964900621875000, 
 289422779189065388729739884727261311335523876525826827610837878/
  13830679166868001716867423295040157079422142313488951098808292466964844191875, 
 73290141789900682346236756296281632385700435136761734854978169/
  4760232772372853715100687840239153223752458332702758493946164281704448000000, 
 1328000670687269568251237056898750099240539693943729290534859064704/
  116143884255821527025427069419063185471931245931010564922481134542808762300828125, 
 534914459536669165837032415124401384018548432231748244265236035901669/
  62442685051458162431743762678741769113521152505631206144419505724000962743812566000, 
 3630775422414635277391824836016792455046434265356053068966904793686127/
  561046661122723333477527580217834530341681234511042139318237633191176948931136484375, 
 20513877099465942992601578051850258265893486440485946585610975418511/
  4163455280753355143670836669453639362091731555059361717186184830622856628939046400, 
 49270886082316147828908728873482271633331471000347758524399465553214486348/
  13037426963106552646473857502013262277097624442051812762246735747244405771493578337890625, 
 4548762309256992429583507979158779618203990768088647241482470163433500441627/
  1558292057275284971294401987919899114572909306261892534919882071859237275668493238671875000, 
 967582626578947636985056197133951478489213134116051238079958495980070779011/
  426297995395862736856988937319358038502769131216083513986545268504401503387661333133468375, 
 175632770923183651370783090743605423528917741780007476960458007342660789311261/
  98891933220901626839165266619724532574369243967161550163015812751194706963678909595520000000, 
 2371481543528462185588615597023449204675724600081528986829128176587258969557369392/
  1696289215193089066661382938658599776946091899112035044497879998063588761952999364581278641238455};
```

Plotting the points shows a smooth behaviour

```
ListLogPlot[toDetermine]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which gives me hope that there is an exact expression. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the reciprocals of the numbers in  the list.

Comment: Tried that, but nothing happened

Comment: Okay, I suggest try taking logarithms of the numbers in the list.

Comment: Do you mean feeding `FindSequenceFunction` `Log` of the numbers? Still no result. Or do you mean to pass `FindSequenceFunction` some numerical approximations of some logs of the numbers? Does `FindSequenceFunction` work with non-exact numbers?

Comment: I apologize. I thought you were using `FindFormula` which is similar but quite different. Don't be surprised that `FindSequenceFunction` has many limitations in its ability to find good functions.

Comment: I have had a lot of success in the past with `FindSequenceFunction`. I have never managed to get `FindFormula` to give me an exact result like `FindSequenceFunction` does. Do you have any tips on how to use it? For me it usually produces an answer that is a `Piecewise` function, which is not what I want

Comment: You are correct about the two functions. It is very likely that the numbers you have got are too much to handle for `FindsequenceFunction`. Without knowing the context in which the numbers arise, it is not possible to give good advice.

Comment: @Somos I have 80 numbers now, but no sucess on obtaining a general formula. The context is physics and the asymptotic expansion of a function. These are the coefficients of a certain term in that expansion as a function of an integer parameter that more or less denotes a fourier mode number which initialises the whole computation. For each mode number I perform the expansion and obtain a coefficient. I want to general expression for that coeffiecient as a function of the mdoe number.